# Cin is not working with array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, cin

When I try to get from user a username, I make the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void main(){
char *usrn=new char[20]; //Max username length of 20 alfanumeric characters
    std::string usrn_str;
        while (true){
            std::cout << "Enter the username(3-20 characters): "; 
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            std::cin.getline(usrn,22);
            usrn_str=usrn;
            if ((usrn_str.length())<3){
                cout << "Introduced username too short!" << endl;
            }
            else if ((usrn_str.length())>=21){
                cout << "Introduced username too long!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << usrn_str.c_str() ;
            }
        }
}
```

Anyway, when introducing a larger username than the allowed one, i.e 25, it shows me the message that the introduced username is too long, but in the next loop, I can't enter again the username, because it takes as I've entered the last 5 characters in the mentioned example. Summing up, if I enter a 30 length username, it discards the first 20 and sets the last 10 ones as the username, when I want to be asking the username till I get a 3-20 length username.

How could I implement it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `std::cin.ignore(256,'\n')`

Comment: Use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), read in the entire username and then check the size.  If it is too big then repeat.

Comment: Why are you using that pointer to char at all? Use `std::string` and you'll be fine.

Comment: `cout << usrn_str.c_str() ;`  -- You are aware that `<<` is overloaded for `std::string`?  There is no need for `c_str()`, just `usrn_str`.  Also, you forgot to `#include <string>`.

Comment: `char *usrn=new char[20];` but `std::cin.getline(usrn,22);`?? What about these additional two bytes?

Comment: Because I'm using Winsock client-server connection, and in order to send the username, I need it to be *char type. @ForceBru

Comment: In order to check wether it is larger or not. If I set `cin.getline(usrn,20)`, I won't be able to check its length because it will always be shorter than 20 @πάντα-ῥεῖ

Comment: @Zarauztarra - `Because I'm using Winsock client-server connection,`  -- That is no excuse to use char*.  You can work entirely using `std::string`, and only at that time when you need to pass a const char*, would you use `c_str()`.

Comment: If I do that, I get an error that `const char* is not compatible with parameter type char*` @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Zarauztarra What is the name of this function, and does it really change the contents of the buffer you're sending?  To get around the error send `&usrn_str[0]` instead if you are using C++11 or greater.  Or use `std::vector<char>` and do the same.

Comment: Oh I solved it. It was a matter of changing the function argument from `char *` to `const char *`. Thanks to all! @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::getline()` to read the whole user input (user input is line based). Then do the validation checkes against the input line.

```
bool        finished = false;
std::string name;
do
{
    if (std::getline(std::cin, name))
    {
          // You have successfully read one line of user input.
          // User input is line based so this is usually the answer to
          // one question.
          //
          // Do your validation checks here.
          // If the user entered data that checks out then set
          // finished to true.
    }
    else
    {
          // There was a problem reading the line.
          // You need to reset the stream to a good state
          // before proceeding or exit the application.
    }
}
while(!finished);
```